# Store temporary variables c# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to store temp variable within application so it needs to do like this:

```
Open form1
From form1 > Open form2
Inside form2 > change value of temp variable
Close Form2
use temp variable in form1 or some other form
```

These are the steps so you can imagine what i want. One option is to store it in file in %temp%, but is there some way to store it inside application since it will be 2-5 int.

EDIT: So you didn't get it, point is that i want to have some 'TEMP VALUE' accessible from any form in any time, i just want to create it in from2 and then use it in any other form

Comment: Make use of static variables

Comment: What do you mean by a temp variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use static class and static variables:

```
public static class ClassTemp 
{
  public static string myVariable {get;set;}
}
```

To access it in your forms:

```
 ClassTemp.myVariable = "Hello World";
```